# Change variable globally inside setInterval()

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I'm trying to display how many seconds have passed with a setInterval function in JavaScript embedded in HTML. I tried the code below, however it only outputs 1, but it seems like the test function isn't executed more than once.
Any help would be much appreciated!

```
var n=1;
function test() {
    document.write(n);
n=n+1;
}
setInterval(test(), 1000);
```

Comment: `setInterval(test, 1000)` — by including the `()` you're calling the function and passing its result to `setTimeout()`.

Comment: You should not use document.write, why have courses not updated this.....

Answer (score 3):

Remove the parenthesis after function name. Simply specify the name of the function.

```js
var n=1;
function test() {
  document.write(n);
  n=n+1;
}
setInterval(test, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should also work!

```js
var n=1;
function test() {
    document.write(n);
    n=n+1;
}
setInterval(() => test(), 1000);
```

Edit: don't do this, it creates an unnecessary function!

Comment: This only creates an unnecessary new function.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var n=1;

function test() {
  document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = n;
  n+=1;
}

setInterval(()=>{
  test()
  }, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="counter">0</div>
```

Comment: You should consider adding an explanation of what you did and how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var n=1;
function test() {
    document.write(n);
n=n+1;
}
setInterval(test, 1000);
```

Remove the ()

Answer (score 0):

You should remove parentheses of function in `setInterval` to calling target function.

```js
var n=1;
function test() {
  document.write(n);
  n=n+1;
}
setInterval(test, 1000);
```

Also you can write second number in special element instead of using `write()` to better working

```js
var n = 0;
function test() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML = n+=1;
}
setInterval(test, 1000);
```

```html
<div>0</div>
```